# Saber si un correo se ha recivido con phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hola a todos tengo una página que cuando un usuario se registra recibe un correo de bienvenida con phpMailer.
Todo funciona correctamente pero me he dado cuenta que si me invento la dirección de correo también se envía y no me avisa que esa cuenta correo no existe. Estoy usando una cuenta de GMAIL para mandar los correos, y en esa cuenta si me llega un correo de GMAIL como que ese email no existe o no se pudo entregar.
¿Se puede hacer que phpMailer detecte que el correo no existe?
Valora esta pregunta
Me gusta: Está pregunta es útil y esta claraNo me gusta: Está pregunta no esta clara o no es útil
0

Comment: Si usas una cuenta de gmail los retornos iran hacia ella, no hacia phpmailer, por lo tanto la respuesta es **no**, phpmailer no es capaz de detectar si el correo existe o no existe, pues phpmailer solo gestiona la salida hacia tu MTA, que en tu caso parece ser gmail, y luego se desentiende por completo de lo que suceda con el.

Comment: Lo que se suele hacer es indicar al usuario que valide de algún modo haber recibido el correo, sea devolviendo un mensaje de confirmación, sea yendo a una URL de validación o algo así. Esto no tiene nada que ver con PHPMailer, como bien indica @masterguru, el cual es una simple herramienta para enviar el correo. Una vez enviado, el correo queda en el terreno del usuario, sólo él debe decidir qué hacer, si confirmar que recibió el mensaje o no, etc. Aunque hay otros parámetros, por ejemplo, que el mensaje vaya a Spam, tampoco en eso PHPMailer te va a ayudar.

Comment: Gracias Masterguru y @A.Cedano por responder, yo no he podido hacerlo antes por motivo de trabajo. Creo que lo he entendido, a ver por eso muchos foros cuando te registras te mandan un enlace a tu correo para que lo valides. Lo que voy a  hacer es crear una tabla con el id del usuario y un campo que ponga 'validado' por ejemplo y mandare en el correo un enlace con una petición a esa tabla para que se ponga por ejemplo a ' true '.Cuando el usuario quiera ' ingresar ' en la página además de comprobar usuario y contraseña comprobare ese campo también.